# Common BreakPoints for Reponsive Design

Tags: html, css

**What are some common Breakpoints to achieve the responsive layout for web pages**

I use basically

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
}

@media screen and (min-resolution: 150dpi) {
}

@media screen and (max-resolution: 300dpi) {
}

@media screen and (min-width: 150px) {
}

@media screen and (min-height: 100px){
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
}
```

I'm using above mentioned breakpoints but could not achieve complete responsive layout

Comment: So don't use media at all?

Comment: The "best" is none at all. Websites are responsive by default. It's the fancy designs that make them not so.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol why the best is to use nothing at all?

Comment: Because any media query at all is a cost. A performance cost, but also a cost of extra development time to make sure it works.

Answer (score 3):

**Major Breakpoints**

As a developer we need to adapt  design to three type of device (mobile, tablet, and desktop). You should use at least 3breakpoints for the most device flexibility.
Following are some major breakpoints

**These breakpoints i mostly use:**

**0 - 600px:** Phone

**600 - 900px:**    Tablet portrait

**900 - 1200px:**   Tablet landscape

**[1200 - 1800]** is where our normal styles apply

**1800px + :**     Big desktop

Visit to see [statistics](https://gs.statcounter.com/screen-resolution-stats/), these are the 6 most common screen sizes

Comment: thank you, That's a great guideline , It would be great to stick note it on the wall :)

Comment: welcome :) really happy its beneficial for u

Answer (score 3):

It is up to you and the usage of your website. Most of the websites designed today uses mobile first approach. The breakpoints can be same as bootstrap uses.

```
// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```